# Why is this grid not even?

Tags: python, processing

It's probably something extremely obvious, but I can't seem to find why the first to columns in the grid are the same.

```
grid = [[1]*8 for n in range(8)]

cellWidth = 70

def is_odd(x):
    return bool(x - ((x>>1)<<1))

def setup():
    size(561, 561)

def draw():
    x,y = 0,0
    for xrow, row in enumerate(grid):
        for xcol, col in enumerate(row):
            rect(x, y, cellWidth, cellWidth)
            if is_odd(xrow+xcol):
                fill(0,0,0)
            else:
                fill(255)
            x = x + cellWidth
        y = y + cellWidth
        x = 0

def mousePressed():
    print mouseY/cellWidth, mouseX/cellWidth
    print is_odd(mouseY/cellWidth + mouseX/cellWidth)
```

The result I get from the code above is:
[image: checkers board]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this your whole code? When I run it, it exits immediately without drawing anything. If I add a `draw()` call, I get `NameError: global name 'rect' is not defined`

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's the whole code. Are you running this in Processing (in Python mode)?

Comment: No, I'm running it in Python. AFAIK Processing is its own programming language and looks more like Java than the code in this post. Or is there more than one technology with that name...? I'm not up-to-date on these things.

Comment: your is_odd function seems good. I've run the code to generate a boolean 2D-array with your code style, i've got the right result. It should be in your UI code. Dunno where though...

Comment: @Kevin There's Processing.py where you can write in Python. http://py.processing.org/

Comment: `x%2 == 1` is simple and obvious enough that I wouldn't write an `is_odd` function, let alone one as convoluted as `bool(x - ((x>>1)<<1))`

Comment: Completely wild guess: Maybe the `fill` command doesn't change the color of the last rectangle you drew, and instead it changes the color of the next rectangle you'll draw. What happens if you move the `rect` call four lines down, to just above `x = x + cellWidth`?

Comment: @Kevin you are correct. thank you!

Comment: On another note, why is your iteration logic so complicated? Even if you plan on using `row` and `col` at all, you can create `x` by `xrow * cellWidth`, and similar for `y`, without needing any other logic. This will also reduce the rounding error in the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `fill` command doesn't change the color of the last rectangle you drew; instead it changes the color of all the draw calls subsequent to it. According to [the docs](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html):

> Sets the color used to fill shapes. For example, if you run fill(204, 102, 0), all subsequent shapes will be filled with orange.

So all of your colors are lagging one square behind. It's as if all of the tiles were shifted one to the right, except for the leftmost row which is shifted one down and eight to the left. This makes that row mismatch with all the others.

Try putting your `fill` calls before the `rect` call:

```
    for xcol, col in enumerate(row):
        if is_odd(xrow+xcol):
            fill(0,0,0)
        else:
            fill(255)
        rect(x, y, cellWidth, cellWidth)
        x = x + cellWidth
```